# Sorting Items By User Generated Map Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, filter

When a user signs up for my app, they enter their preferences and the items are sorted by a property in their profile called "recommended" which comes from the api: "[Breakfast, Dinner, Desserts, Dine In]"

I have a tab bar where the user can tab through main preferences ie: [All options, food type, beverages] and when the user gets to each preference they get a subset that allows them to sort further that comes from Tabcategories. These are the working examples and the one that doesn't work:

Data comes in via my future:

```
                var productsInHeadings =
                    _getProductsInHeadings(filteredProducts)
                        .where((e) => e.products.length != 0)
                        .toList();
```

Then gets filtered into buckets within the tabs.

```
enum FilterTabs { Breakfast,Rec, Lunch, Dinner, Dessert, All }

typedef void FilterTabCallback(FilterTabs tab);
  List<ProductsInHeading> _getProductsInHeadings(List<Product> items) {
    switch (selectedTab) {
      case FilterTabs.Breakfast:
        final Map<String, List<Product>> allBreakfast =
            Map.fromEntries(TabCategories.breakfast.map((e) => MapEntry(e, [])));

        Map<String, List<Product>> headingItems =
            items.fold(allBreakfast, (breakfast, element) {
          if (!breakfast.containsKey(element.food)) { //food would be classified breakfast, lunch, or dinner
            return breakfast;
          }

          return breakfast
            ..update(element.food, (value) => value..add(element));
        });
        productList = headingItems;
        print("headingItems: $headingItems");

        return headingItems.entries
            .map((e) => ProductsInHeading(e.key, e.value..sort()))
            .toList()
              ..sort()
              ..where((e) => e.products.length != 0);
        break;
}}
```

For each tab in the bucket, then displayed in a separate class

```
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      currentProducts = snapshot.data;

                      return HeaderAndListing(
                          productsInHeading: _currentCat != -1
                              ? productsInHeadings[_currentCat]
                              : productsInHeadings[index],
                          showHeading: selectedTab != FilterTabs.All,
                          restaurant: restaurant,
                          starCount: starCount,
                          rating: rating,
                          filterNum: _currentCat,
                          currentIndex: _tabDetails[selectedTab.index]);
                    },
                  ),
                  Center(child: _subSort(productsInHeadings)),
                ]);
```

This one does not:

```
  case FilterTabs.Rec:
    final Map<String, List<Product>> allRecommended =
        Map.fromEntries(recCategories.map((e) => MapEntry(e, [])));

    Map<String, List> headingItems =
        items.fold(allRecommended, (rec, element) {
      if (!rec.containsKey(userProfile.recommended)) {
        return rec;
      }

      return rec..update(userProfile.recommended, (value) => value..add(element));
    });
    productList = headingItems;
    print("headingItems: $headingItems");

    return headingItems.entries
        .map((e) => ProductsInHeading(e.key, e.value..sort()))
        .toList()
          ..sort()
          ..where((e) => e.products.length != 0);
    break;
```

Why does the first sort work but, the second one does not?

Comment: How are you sorting the list of `ProductsInHeading` without specifying a sorting function? Does that class implement `Comparable`?

Comment: I have data coming in from a future builder. I will update the code.

Comment: That still doesn't explain how you are sorting the list.

Comment: Will update logic structure.

Comment: I updated the structure to show exactly where I'm filtering when the products come into the bucket

Comment: I said sorting. _**Sorting**_. You are calling the `sort` method on a list of `ProductsInHeading`. Custom objects cannot be sorted without either providing a comparison function or implementing `Comparable`. Since there is clearly no comparison function being provided, show how you have implemented `Comparable` in `ProductsInHeading`.

Comment: I'm not using sort as in comparable. I am filtering into buckets. The issue is in: "      return rec..update(userProfile.recommended, (value) => value..add(element));
"
The rec sort cannot resolve : userProfile.recommended  or ( [Breakfast, Dinner, Desserts, Dine In])

Comment: Your question is about sorting, and you are asking why a list isn't being sorted. You call `sort` on lists just before filtering and returning them (which you really should be doing before sorting them since filtering is cheap and sorting is more expensive). So I am asking you to clarify on the details of how you are sorting since that is what your question is actually about.